# aspose: blurred images in png conversion from word file

Tags: java, aspose

I am facing a problem when I have to transform a word document into a png image. The word document has a barcode inside (I have attached the word to transform).
With aspose 10.5 the png generated had the barcode perfectly printed, and it could be readed from barcode readers. 
With aspose 14.12 the barcode is generated a bit blurry, enough to make it unreadable to barcode readers.
This is the code used to convert:

```
ImageSaveOptions options = new ImageSaveOptions(SaveFormat.PNG);
options.setPageIndex(0);
options.setPageCount(1);
options.setResolution(250);
resultingDocument.save( byteArrayOutputStream, options);
```

Do you know if there's any issue with this conversion?

Png with aspose 10.5:
[image]

Png with aspose 14.12:
[image]

Png with aspose 16.1:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to the [latest version of Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/72/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx) and see how it goes on your end. Hope, this helps.

In case the problem still remains, please report this issue in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). Please zip and attach your 1) input Word document, 2) Aspose.Words 10.5.0, 14.12.0 and 16.1.0 generated output PNG files and 3) barcode Font file in your thread for testing.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Hi Awais, I have reported it in the Aspose Words forum, but I still have no answers. This is the link: http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/698703/blurred-images-in-png-conversion-from-word-file.aspx

Comment: To address this problem, we have logged WORDSJAVA-1335 in our issue tracking system. Please follow [this thread](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/698703.aspx) in Aspose.Words forum for further proceedings. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.